# Is Android's requestPermission Java method deprecated?

Tags: android, android-permissions

requestPermission is  the documented Java method using which runtime permissions can be obtained for what they call as dangerous permissions from the user. While their official site still lists it, in Android Studio, it doesn't compile. Has some other things come in its place?

Comment: It's unclear what "doesn't compile", post code snippet of your issue.

Answer (score -1):

Provide more context. Compile error, code snipped, something

Comment: Sorry guys! The method RequestPermissions magically popped up in Android Studio, (not sure why it didn't for the whole day) and I could use it. This thread can be closed.